# How to interpret main effect and interaction between factors that have more than two levels (logistic regression)

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm new to stats and I'm not sure how to interpret the output of my glm model.

I have two fixed factors, task which has two levels (task A and task B), and condition which has four levels (conditions a, b, c, and d). Both factors are sum-coded (because I don't have a clear baseline/reference level).

```
> contrasts(data$condition_c) <- contr.sum(4)
> contrasts(data$condition_c)
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1    0    0
b    0    1    0
c    0    0    1
d   -1   -1   -1
> contrasts(data$task_c) <- contr.sum(2)
> contrasts(data$task_c)
         [,1]
taskA     1
taskB    -1
```

My dependent variable is binary so I'm using logistic regression. The model output looks like this:

```
Call:
glm(formula = DV ~ task_c * condition_c, family = "binomial", 
    data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3678  -1.0629   0.3536   0.9301   1.8400  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           0.26432    0.07572   3.491             0.000482 ***
task_c1               0.20972    0.07572   2.770             0.005611 ** 
condition_c1         -0.22247    0.11058  -2.012             0.044237 *  
condition_c2         -0.09502    0.11226  -0.846             0.397350    
condition_c3          1.98070    0.16615  11.921 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
task_c1:condition_c1 -0.22080    0.11058  -1.997             0.045856 *  
task_c1:condition_c2  0.23499    0.11226   2.093             0.036332 *  
task_c1:condition_c3  0.28610    0.16615   1.722             0.085087 .
```

Can anyone help me understand the main effect of condition and the interaction between task and condition? Thanks!

Am I correct to say that for the main effect of condition, the model summary says that while conditions a and c are significantly different from the grand mean, condition b isn't? What about condition d? And I'm completely lost for the interaction.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! With interactions you shouldn't rely solely on the reports of "significance" of individual model coefficients; you need to use post-modeling tools (like those in the R `car` or `emmeans` packages) to evaluate your hypotheses reliably. I find treatment contrasts easier to explain than sum contrasts; the model is fundamentally the same regardless of how the predictors are coded. It doesn't really matter whether or not you have clear baseline/reference levels for your categorical predictors; you can still just choose 1 as reference arbitrarily (or let R do it for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the intercept. As you have chosen sum/deviation coding, that is a type of average outcome over all levels of the predictors: "the mean of means of the dependent variable at each level of the categorical variable," as this [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATION) puts it. You have two such categorical variables, so the intercept is the estimate at the average over all levels of both of them. With logistic regression, this is in a log-odds scale.

*The main effect of* `condition`

With an interaction between `task` and `condition`, the association of one with outcome depends on the value of the other. With sum/deviation contrasts, the "main effect" coefficient for any level of one of those 2 predictors is the associated difference (here, a log-odds difference) from the intercept ("grand-mean" outcome), evaluated at the "grand mean" over the levels of the other. Is that really of interest by itself, without considering the significant interaction between `task` and `condition`?

What might be of more interest is the *overall* association between `condition` and outcome, taking all of its levels and interactions into account, sometimes called a "chunk test." A [UCLA web page on logistic regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) illustrates that with the `wald.test()` function of the R [`aod` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=aod). If you work within the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) (highly recommended if you are going to do a lot of regression analysis), its `anova()` function (unlike that of base R statistics) provides that type of test.

*What about* `condition d`*?*

With 4 levels of `condition` you only get 3 coefficients. The intercept ("grand mean") includes the effect associated with the 4th level. If you know the "grand mean" over all 4 levels and the differences of the other 3 levels from the grand mean (their individual coefficients under sum/deviation coding), it's simple algebra to get the point estimate of the 4th level, `condition d`. For confidence intervals around that estimate, however, you need to know the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates. That's not included in this model summary, although it's included in the model and accessible via the `vcov()` function.

Post-modeling tools like those provided by the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) can perform such calculations for you. These tools take the choice of predictor coding into account, so that you can typically just use the default R dummy/treatment coding for categorical predictors.*

*The interaction between task and condition*

Two-way interaction coefficients represent *additional* differences beyond what you would otherwise predict, based on the intercept and the individual coefficients for those specific levels of the predictors. I find it easier to think through those interactions with dummy/treatment coding. You can get outcome predictions for any combinations of predictor values, taking all coefficients into account, with post-modeling tools like those in the `emmeans` and `rms` packages.

---

*The only situation I can think of where categorical-variable coding matters is when you perform so-called "Type III ANOVA" tests on a model; dummy/treatment contrasts don't work then. But you probably shouldn't be doing those tests anyway; see the help page for the `Anova()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car).